# How to Read Construction information?? (from blockchain develpment with go)

Tags: blockchain

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract Simple{

    uint256 data;
    string male;
    string name;
    string id;
    function getdata() view public returns(uint256) {
        return data;
    }

    function setdata (uint256 _data) public{
        data= _data;
    }

    function getinfo() view public returns(string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        return (id,male,name);
    }

    function setinfo (string memory _id, string memory _male, string memory _name) public{
        id= _id;
        male= _male;
        name= _name;
    }
}
```

this is my solidity file.. and I used abigen for compiling.
and deploying fine, write contract fine, but
reading has a problem. maybe, there is no error with one parameter in function, but if I use more than 1 parameter function doesn't work...

package main

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "log"

        "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
        "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"

        simple "./contracts/sim" // for demo
)

func main() {
        client, err := ethclient.Dial("/home/paik/ethereum/test_data/geth.ipc")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        address := common.HexToAddress("0xfAD52Ee70d5d264F108834394a4A5EB7ECAaB303")
        instance, err := simple.NewSimple(address, client)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        data, err := instance.Getdata(nil)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("ABC")
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(data) // "1.0"
}
```

[image]